# Is there a bug in the accept rate, or is it just me?

Tags: bug, status-completed

The new accept rate feature seems to not be quite right. For example the user [eric](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/95589/eric) currently has 10 questions, 2 of which are marked as accepted, but a 25% accept rate.

Edit, it looks like a possible cache issue, as now I'm seeing that I have a 25% accept rate for 7 questions, 1 accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read [the rules in the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)? If not, you should.

- Questions must not be community wiki.
- Questions must not be closed.
- Questions must be older than 3 days.
- Questions must have at least 1 answer.
- There must be at least **four** eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the count will not appear.

Also, the tooltip now shows the numbers used in the calculation.

(one final caveat: accept rate is going to be less meaningful here on meta than elsewhere, just because of the nature of meta..)

Comment: and yes, the value is cached very heavily so don't expect it to update in real time..

Comment: I'd not seen the blog, I understand the desire to cache the results, and in my case that explains why the result is 25% rather than 20% as this question is too new. But that means the value will always be incorrect if a question has been asked in the last 3 days (ok it may be accurate by chance). Won't that just confuse people?

Comment: I don't know, Rich, not sure I can take you seriously what with your miniscule 25% accept rate. With that sketchy track record how do I know this answer will stand a chance of being accepted? :)

Comment: How do closed questions count?

Comment: what does the edit from status-by-design to status-completed signify? The additional bullets in your answer?

Comment: the tooltip shows the underlying numbers to reduce confusion.