# Bug in the accepted % calculation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a bug in the accept rate, or is it just me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16630/is-there-a-bug-in-the-accept-rate-or-is-it-just-me)

On [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432952/why-does-html-markup-often-use-and-as-delimiting-quotes) on SO, the asker has a 100% accept rate. But, the question doesn't have an accepted answer. Thinking it could be a rounding error, I checked out [his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153545/pavium). However, he's got only 8 questions, 7 of which are accepted. So, his accept rate should be 88%, right?

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16630/is-there-a-bug-in-the-accept-rate-or-is-it-just-me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accept rate is only recalculated 3 days after asking the question.

From the feature announcement [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)

> - Questions must not be community wiki.

- Questions must not be closed.
- Questions must be more than 3 days old.
- Questions must have at least 1 answer.
- There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation can be incredibly backlogged due to the very intensive caching that is going on. Aside from the items that Diago pointed out, you have to also remember that it may be a while before the cache refreshes the calculation.